# Is there an R function to parse a compound coordinate reference system?

Tags: r, r-sf

I have recently started to work with airborne LiDAR data that has a compound coordinate reference system consisting of a horizontal (projected) and vertical component. An example, with code to create a compound CRS object from a WKT description, is shown below.

I'm deriving various raster layers from the LiDAR point cloud and I want to assign just the horizontal component of the compound CRS to each of these (EPSG:7856 in the example). Does anyone know of an existing package function that will extract the horizontal PROJCRS component reliably, i.e. allowing for a variety of old and new CRS definitions?

**Update 2021-11-01:** Tweaked the original example of a WKT string to provide code to create a compound CRS object in R.

```
# Create a compound CRS object of the type used for
# publicly available LiDAR point cloud data in Australia.
# Requires the glue and sf packages.
#
wkt <- glue::glue('COMPOUNDCRS["GDA2020 / MGA zone 56 + AHD height - AUSGeoid2020 (Meters) (with axis order normalized for visualization) (with axis order normalized for visualization)",
    PROJCRS["GDA2020 / MGA zone 56",
        BASEGEOGCRS["GDA2020",
            DATUM["Geocentric Datum of Australia 2020",
                ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
            PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
            ID["EPSG",7844]],
        CONVERSION["UTM zone 56S",
            METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
                ID["EPSG",9807]],
            PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                ID["EPSG",8801]],
            PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",153,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                ID["EPSG",8802]],
            PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
                SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
                ID["EPSG",8805]],
            PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                ID["EPSG",8806]],
            PARAMETER["False northing",10000000,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                ID["EPSG",8807]]],
        CS[Cartesian,2],
            AXIS["easting",east,
                ORDER[1],
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
            AXIS["northing",north,
                ORDER[2],
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        ID["EPSG",7856]],
    VERTCRS["AHD height - AUSGeoid2020 (Meters)",
        VDATUM["Australian Height Datum"],
        CS[vertical,1],
            AXIS["gravity-related height",up,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        ID["EPSG",5711]]]')

# Create the compound CRS object
compound_crs <- st_crs(wkt)
```

Comment: Hi @michael. Not sure if I can figure it out . But to make it easier to find a solution, would it be possible to provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Hi @lovalery. I'm not sure - what should an example include in addition to the WKT posted in the question?

Comment: Hi @michael. If we could download one of your files (or an extract of one of your files) to generate the sf object with the `COMPOUNDCRS` part, that would be great.

Comment: Thanks @lovalery. I'm loathe to post a download link because I gather that is not considered consistent with a minimal reproducible example on SO, but I've tweaked the example in the question to show code to create a compound CRS in R that is identical to one used by the LiDAR data that I'm working with.

Comment: Thanks @michael for sharing an example of `compound CRS` as well as the `get_horizontal_crs()` function you have developed. To answer your question, I'm not at all sure that the function you are looking for exists in an R package. However, I guess the solution is in the `PROJ` library: two functions exist natively, namely `extractGeographicCRS()` and `extractVerticalCRS()`. To tell the truth, I have never installed this library directly and know even less how to use it from R! So sorry I can't help you better. Anyway, I hope someone can tell us how to use these two functions from R... Cheers.

Comment: No worries @lovalery. It's very good to know about those PROJ functions. Looking at the sf sources, there are calls to PROJ C functions. I'll try posting a feature request at the sf GitHub repo.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @michael. Yes, this is a great initiative! These functions are useful and I don't think it is a major challenge to implement them in the `sf` package for someone like Edzer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trawling through the R spatial jungle I haven't yet found an existing function to extract the horizontal CRS component. The function below is my attempt to write one. I've tested it with old and new LiDAR data, where the older data has a simple (just horizontal) CRS and the new data has a compound CRS.

I'm sure there must be an existing and better way.

**Update 2021-11-01:** Tweaked the function to accept any spatial object compatible with the `sf::st_crs()` function.

```
# Retrieve the horizontal component of a compound CRS.
# The object x can be an 'sf' package 'crs' object or any
# spatial object from which a CRS can be queried using the
# sf::st_crs function.
#
get_horizontal_crs <- function(x) {
  xcrs <- sf::st_crs(x)
  if (is.na(xcrs)) stop("No CRS defined")

  wkt <- sf::st_as_text(xcrs)
  
  if (!grepl("COMPD_CS", wkt)) {
    # Should just be a horizontal CRS - simply return it
    xcrs
  } else {
    # Extract the horizontal component
    i <- regexpr("PROJCS\\[", wkt)
    wkt <- substring(wkt, i)
    
    # Match square brackets to discard any trailing
    # component (e.g. the vertical CRS)
    wkt_chars <- strsplit(wkt, "")[[1]]
    level <- 1
    k <- match("[", wkt_chars)
    while (level > 0) {
      k <- k + 1
      if (wkt_chars[k] == '[') {
        level <- level + 1
      } else if (wkt_chars[k] == ']') {
        level <- level - 1
      }
    }
    
    wkt <- substring(wkt, 1, k)
    
    sf::st_crs(wkt)
  }
}
```

Comment: Reluctantly accepted my own answer for the moment - but still hoping someone can suggest a better approach. A request for this facility to be implemented in the `sf` package was not supported (https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1831).